# R Combine two gsub() statements

Tags: r, gsub

I have these two lines of R codes:

```
df$symbol <- gsub("\\^", "-P", df$symbol)   # find "^" and change it to "-P"
df$symbol <- gsub("/", "-", df$symbol)      # find "/" and change it to "-"
```

How can I combine them into one line?

Thank you!

Comment: this might help https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/textclean/versions/0.9.3/topics/mgsub

Comment: Thanks!  I tried qdap::mgsub() many times and received error message: could not find function "mgsub"

Comment: sorry, I referred to the "wrong" package. I wanted to point to `mgsub` from the `mgsub` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgsub/vignettes/Safe-Substitution.html

Comment: I also tried mgsub::mgsub(), same error: could not find function "mgsub".  My RStudio is quite stubborn.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have two different replacement strings, there may not be a way to do this with just a single call to `gsub`.  However, you could chain two calls to `gsub` here:

```r
df$symbol <- gsub("/", "-", gsub("\\^", "-P", df$symbol))
```